# Is it possible to build a table with strings of dingbats instead of horizontal rules?

Tags: tables, postscript

I know you can make or create an table with `tabbing` or `tabular`. But is it possible to build a table with dingbats instead of `\hline`s?

My code so far you could  make the top line with

```
\dingline{190}
```

But how could you make a complete table like this?

```
\begin{tabular}{rlcr}
 \hline
 Place & Name & Goals & Points \\
 \hline\hline
 1. & SV Werder Bremen & 11 & 9 \\
 2. & SC Freiburg & 5 & 4 \\
 3. & Bayer 04 Leverkusen & 6 & 3 \\
 3. & Bayern München & 4 & 1 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "with postscript" (the question in the title) or "with ASCII symbols" (the apparently completely different question in the body)? Clearly you could write (or generate) a postscript file that typesets that table without using TeX at all, but what is the connection to TeX that you are asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modified `\dingfill` could do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pifont}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xdingfill}[2][]{%
  \leavevmode\cleaders\hbox{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {\mbox}{\makebox[#1]}{\Pisymbol{pzd}{#2}}%
  }\hfill\kern\z@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rlcr}
\multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{\xdingfill{190}}\\
 Place & Name & Goals & Points \\
\multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{\xdingfill{190}}\\
\multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{\xdingfill{190}}\\
 1. & SV Werder Bremen & 11 & 9 \\
 2. & SC Freiburg & 5 & 4 \\
 3. & Bayer 04 Leverkusen & 6 & 3 \\
 3. & Bayern München & 4 & 1 \\
\multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{\xdingfill{190}}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use `\xdingfill[0.2in]{190}` to get the same as the original `\dingfill`; each symbol will be put in a box as wide as specified by the optional argument (no optional argument means natural width).

Comment: Yes, I think that looks ugly enough for what OP is wanting...

Comment: @Brent.Longborough The customer's always right. `;-)`